# Stopwatch appears to jump 500µs between iterations of a tight loop

Tags: c#

I wrote some code which monitors the output of Stopwatch using a tight loop. This loop tracks the number of ticks which have elapsed since the last iteration. I'm observing jumps of 500 microseconds 20 times a second, while most other iterations take <1µs.

Can someone explain why I'm seeing these jumps?

I've tried:

1. Setting processor affinity (no effect)
2. Changing thread priority (Highest/AboveNormal makes things worse)
3. Running outside of the debugger
4. Release build with optimizations

My code is below:

```
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        int crossThresholdCount = 0;
        long lastElapsedTicks = 0;
        long lastPrintTicks = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("IsHighResolution: " + Stopwatch.IsHighResolution);
        Console.WriteLine("Frequency: " + Stopwatch.Frequency);

        sw.Start();

        long thresholdTicks = 5000;  // 10000 ticks per ms
        while (true)
        {
            long tempElapsed = sw.ElapsedTicks;
            long sincePrev = tempElapsed - lastElapsedTicks;
            lastElapsedTicks = tempElapsed;

            if (sincePrev > thresholdTicks)
                crossThresholdCount++;

            // print output 
            if (crossThresholdCount > 0 && tempElapsed - lastPrintTicks > TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond)
            {
                lastPrintTicks = tempElapsed;
                Console.WriteLine("crossed " + crossThresholdCount + " times");
                crossThresholdCount = 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried to run your test code twice in your program to eliminate JIT effect ?

Comment: What happens if you replace the console.writeline code with a store to list variable, and then print out the timings all at once AFTER the loop has completed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you are seeing preemptive task switching. This is when the operating system suspends your program, and goes off to execute other programs. This is how things have been since Windows 95 (Win 3.1 and earlier had cooperative multitasking, whereby you could hold the CPU for as long as you want).

By the way, there is a better way to time your execution accurately: [`QueryThreadCycleTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which counts CPU cycles only when your code is executing, and so excludes such pauses.

Comment: Win 3.1 actually did preemptive multitasking for DOS applications and cooperative multitasking for Windows applications.

Comment: Wouldn't setting the thread priority to Highest reduce/prevent preempting? When I set it to highest, the number of jumps go from 20 per second to 200 per second

Comment: @noahchen The number itself is not everything; it could be that your program goes from 20 1ms slices per second to 200 4ms slices per second, which is obviously an improvement.

Answer (score 3):

Your test doesn't really make sense... Your process is not the only one to run on your machine. The system gives processor time to each thread in turn, so there are periods of time when your loop is not running at all, which explains the "jumps".